# Finding points within a contour using OpenCV

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, geometry

For any general contour I was wondering if there was a method that could find an arbitrary amount of different points within it using OpenCV.

[sample random contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MveQW.png)

I'd like to be able to find an arbitrary amount of different points within the white region. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you exactly mean by saying "arbitrary amount of different points" ? Can you be more clear ?

Comment: I mean If I want 10 points, it’ll give me 10 distinct points that are all different and inside the contour. If I want N points, I’ll get N points, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built in way to do that. Here's a potential solution:

This works only if there are just 2 contour levels AND the entire contour line is within the image (as is the case with the picture you linked).

Suppose that you're working with a black/white image (the pixels in the white contour lines are simply 1, and all other pixels are 0).
And let region 0 be the part of the image outside the white line and region 1 be the part inside.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Open the image
img = cv2.imread('<file_path_to_image>')

# Get its dimensions
height, width, __ = img.shape

# Create an array of zeros with the same dimensions as the image...
levels = np.zeros((height, width))

for i in range(height):
    current_region = 0
    for j in range(width):

        # If this pixel is white (it's a contour line), you're transitioning either from region 0 to 1, or the other way around
        if image[i][j]:
            current_region == 1 if current_region==0 else 0
        
        # But if the pixel is black, just record it's region into the new array
        else:
            levels[i][j] = current_region

# So now the array 'levels' has all the info you need. 
# The pixels inside the contour are 1; the ones outside are 0.
```